# Gmail to always reply to myself

Tags: gmail, phpmailer

Using PHPMAILER class to send email from my website to my gmail account, if I try to response this consult gmail puts this gmail account as destination address.
This issue happens only with gmail, yahoo for example works fine.
The code I'm using to send from the form:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSendmail();
$body = "body of consult";

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->From = "user@hotmail.com"; // sender
$mail->FromName = "User Name"; // sender
$mail->addReplyTo("user@hotmail.com","User Name"); // sender
$mail->AddAddress("myaccount@gmail.com", "my name"); //destination (Me)
$mail->Subject = "User Subject";
$mail->AltBody = ""; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  return(false);
} else {
  return(true);
}
```

Is there any value o function to add to phpmailer class?

I appreciate any help.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

This is a gmail limitation. It does not let you send from arbitrary "from" addresses, only your account address. You can add additional aliases in your gmail preferences, but you can't use a non-gmail address.

This is covered in the PHPMailer documentation.